Select which point to start with when bridge edge loops
I've created two electron-orbit-like curves (with same number of vertices on it) with python script and I want to operate bridge edge loops on them to create a tie in such electron-orbit-like shape.

Sometimes I would get what I want, like this:

But in other situation, blender will start with connecting wrong vertex pairs and finally generate a mess, like this:

My question is, is there any way I can manually select which vertex pair to start with when bridging edge loops?
